# Android Https connection.

Tags: android, https

I am trying to establish a https connection in android. I made both http and https connection to https://encrypted.google.com, but both connections gave the same response. I could not understand the reason. How can I test my https connection codes work correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the same response is the point. You would be in trouble if you didn't :) HTTPS encrypts the underlying communications channel, but you are still dealing with HTTP on top of that. If each application needed to be re-written to use HTTPS, it wouldn't be very useful.

As for testing, you can use a package capture tool (tcpdump, Wireshark) and see the difference yourself. When using HTTP, you will be able to see all data that is being sent or received in plain text; it will be encrypted if using HTTPS.